# Changing cardheader title color dynamically in a Cardslib Cardlist

Tags: android, listview, cardslib

I create a list of cards with the cardLib library with the CardListView.

I get the text for the cards from different arraylists, my problem is want to change the color of the actual top header title of the card, not just the inner title.

I have only figured out code that works for the inner title:

In my for loop for creating the list in my fragment:

```
 switch (statuser.get(j)){

                case "Aflyst!":
                    card.setColor(Color.RED);
                    break;

                case "Ændret!":
                    card.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                break;

            }
```

My class for the card, with the "setupInnerViewElements":

public class ModulCard extends Card {

```
public String title1; //just an example... use gettes and setters

public int color;

public void setColor(int color) {
    this.color = color;
}

public void setTitle1(String title1) {
    this.title1 = title1;
}

public ModulCard(Context context) {
    super(context, R.layout.modul_card);
}

@Override
public void setupInnerViewElements(ViewGroup parent, View view) {
    TextView tx = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.card_main_inner_simple_title);
    tx.setText(title1);

    tx.setTextColor(color);

    addCardHeader(mCardHeader);

}

}
```

card layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="10dp" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/card_main_inner_simple_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:textColor="@color/Gray"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

This changes the color of the "card_main_inner_simple_title" but, i don't know how to change the color of the actual header title. Do i need to make a costum header to do this?

[**LINK TO LIBRARY**](https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/cardslib)

Thank you

Comment: You should post a link to the library since `CardsLib` is not from Google.

Comment: oh yes, absolutely, just added it to the original post and here : https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/cardslib

Comment: You have to set the  color in the setupInnerViewElements of your CardHeader.